# Match data without pattern matching

Tags: haskell

How can I check if a variable is of a certain data type without pattern matching?

```
data MyData = A | B | C char
            deriving (Eq)

-- This works.
isA :: MyData -> Bool
isA x = x == A

-- This generates a compile error.
isC :: MyData -> Bool
isC x = x == C
```

Edit: Forgot to add `deriving Eq`.

Comment: In a word: no. But you can use the `C{}` pattern if you don’t want to write out all the fields.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid pattern matching? It's a fundamental part of Haskell.

Comment: Why do you want to check the constructor alone? In the vast majority of cases, after you discover that `x` is a `C something` you'll want to know what is `something`. Pattern matches solves this simply. The `isA,...` functions may be symptoms of _boolean blindness_, where all the relevant information is compressed into a boolean, losing most of it in the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a point of terminology, you're checking if a variable matches a certain data *constructor*, not *type*.  All your values are of type `MyData`; you're checking which constructor they match.

That being said, there is no good reason to avoid pattern matching.  In fact, the correct idiomatic way in Haskell to implement `isA` is:

```
isA A = True
isA _ = False
```

or, if you prefer:

```
isA x = case x of { A -> True; _ -> False }
```

Likewise, correct ways to implement `isC` are:

```
isC (C _) = True
isC _ = False
```

or:

```
isC x = case x of { C _ -> True; _ -> False }
```

If you are trying to avoid pattern matching because you are concerned that it is somehow less efficient than testing equality, disabuse yourself of this notion.  It is the most efficient way to determine the constructor of a value.

If you are trying to avoid pattern matching because you dislike the syntax or have some kind of personal distaste for the technique, then you have my sympathies:  learning Haskell will be a miserable experience for you.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge even your first example would not compile without an error

```
> ghci
...
Prelude> data MyData = A | B | C Char
Prelude> isA x = x == A

<interactive>:2:9: error:
    • No instance for (Eq MyData) arising from a use of ‘==’
    • In the expression: x == A
      In an equation for ‘isA’: isA x = x == A
```

which can be fixed easily by

```
Prelude> data MyData = A | B | C Char deriving (Eq)
```

@Alexis King's <strike>advice</strike> comment defining

```
isC x = x == C{}
```

will compile but raise a run time error

```
isC (C 'a')
*** Exception: <interactive>:6:14-17: Missing field in record construction
```

---

If I view this correctly this is a special case of `(a -> b)` having no `Eq` instance - because in general you cannot (reasonably) define `==` say for something like `[Double] -> Int` - the only reasonable definition same input data yield same output data - is not feasible.

### Note:

If you accept pattern matching - you do not need the additional `deriving (Eq)` for the `isA`, `isB` and `isC` pattern matching does not need this.

---

I have found another weird way - but we also need to change the type and use a Language Pragma:

```hs
Prelude> :set -XDeriveFunctor
Prelude> data MyData a = A | B | C a deriving (Eq, Functor)
Prelude> isC x = fmap (const True) x == C True
Prelude> isC x = fmap (const ()) x == C ()
```

### Remark

I think your question is a bit like - can I ride the bicycle without legs - the answer is well kind of you need a special bike for that. Or in your case - it works if you have `deriving Eq` and type constructors without any parameters.

Comment: The last “e” from `True` got split off. Also, you could've used `fmap (const ()) x == C ()`. Since the internal value is irrelevant, the unit type is in a sense the “more appropriate” choice.

Comment: I don't think someone recommended `isC x = x == C{}` - but pattern matching on the constructor `C` , i.e. `isC C{} = True; isC _ = False` which saves you writing wildcards for every field of the constructor.